# Trouble calling base constructor - getting read access violation

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm setting up a program that uses 'DFS' as a child class of 'Search', and calls its base constructor.

The program runs fine, until the breakpoint I placed just after calling the constructor, in which I receive the error:

Exception thrown: read access violation.
_Pnext was 0xCCCCCCD0.

I've tried to summarise the code to only what is important.

in main.cpp:

```cpp
DFS search(gridSize, startPoint, endPoints, walls);
```

in Search.h:

```cpp
public:
    Search(unsigned int gridSize, unsigned int startPoint, unsigned int endPoints[2], vector<int> walls);
```

in Search.cpp:

```cpp
#include "Search.h"

Search::Search(unsigned int gridSize, unsigned int startPoint, unsigned int endPoints[2], vector<int> walls)
{
    sGridSize = gridSize;
    sStartPoint = startPoint;
    sEndPoints[2] = endPoints[2];
    sWalls = walls;
}
```

In DFS.h:

```cpp
#include "Search.h"

#include <vector>

public:
    DFS(unsigned int gridSize, unsigned int startPoint, unsigned int endPoints[2], vector<int> walls);
```

In DFS.cpp:

```cpp
#include "DFS.h"

DFS::DFS(unsigned int gridSize, unsigned int startPoint, unsigned int endPoints[2], vector<int> walls) : Search(gridSize, startPoint, endPoints, walls)
{

}
```

If any more code is needed to understand this, just ask - I'm worried about pasting in too much.

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ Thats a poor duplicate. Its just a duplicate of the symptoms of something going wrong, not what actually went wrong. Just my 2c anyway.

Comment: @MikeVine Well, it's along the old saying: [_"give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime"_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_a_man_a_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_day;_teach_a_man_to_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_lifetime)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `sEndPoints[2] = endPoints[2]` you access the ***third*** element of the two-element arrays. And you assign only that value.

The C++ solution is to use [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead of "old" C-style arrays. Or [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

And if you don't want to do that then the solution is to use *constructor initializer lists* where you initialize the member variables instead of assigning to them. For example

```
Search::Search(unsigned int gridSize, unsigned int startPoint, unsigned int endPoints[2], vector<int> walls)
    : sGridSize(gridSize), sStartPoint(startPoint), sEndPoints(endPoints), sWalls(walls)
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks man - using std::array seems to have fixed my problem :)